# How do we determine the membership functions and values for this problem?

Tags: ai-design, fuzzy-logic

The goal of our project is to identify the quality of a grain and we have two values, `A` and `B`.

`A` can take the values low  `L`, medium `M` and high `H`. And `B` can take the values of Low, Medium and High (`L`,`M`,`H`).
 Specifically, the ranges for `A` are -> `5-10` (low), `10-15` (medium), `15-20` (high). 
And the ranges for `B` are -> `50-75` (low), `75-90` (medium), `90-110` (high)

The output for these are bad `B`, average `A` and good `G`.

[image: The sample table is shown here]

How do we determine the membership functions and values for this?

We want to write Python code for the fuzzy system, but we are beginners and have no idea how to go about this. Any help would be appreciated.